Laravel Livewire: data is not updated
I have such a component. The payment button is not active until the user selects a payment option and method
return-ad.blade.php
@php use App\Models\UserLimit; @endphp
<div>
    @if ($template == 'mini')
        @if ($estate->active_to > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
            <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="moveToActive()"><i
                    class="ico-corner-up-left"></i><span>@lang('app.Restore')</span></a>
        @else
            <a href="#return-{{$estate_id}}" class="btn-change-modal"><i
                    class="ico-corner-up-left"></i><span>@lang('app.Restore')</span></a>
        @endif
    @else
        @if ($estate->active_to > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
            <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="moveToActive()" class="primary-btn flex size2 mb-16">
                <div class="btn-text">@lang('app.Restore')</div>
            </a>
        @else
            <a href="#return-{{$estate_id}}" class="primary-btn flex size2 mb-16 btn-change-modal">
                <div class="btn-text">@lang('app.Restore')</div>
            </a>
        @endif
    @endif
    <div class="wrapper-custom-modal size2" id="return-{{$estate_id}}">
        <form class="modal-custom" wire:submit="pay">
            <div class="close-btn-style close-btn-modal"><i class="ico-close-l"></i></div>
            <div class="caption">@lang('app.Restore ad')</div>
            @php
                $limit = Auth::guard('web')->user()->getLimit(NULL, NULL, UserLimit::TYPE_RETURN);
                $amount = $limit['free'] + $limit['pay'];
            @endphp
            @if ($amount > 0)
                <div
                    class="gray-style-1 mb-16">@lang('app.Balance')</div>
                <button type="button" wire:click="byLimit()"
                        class="btn-dark secondary mb-16 btnSend height-48 full-width">@lang('app.Restore')</button>
            @else
                <div class="one-benefit-modal">
                    <div class="caption-m">@lang('app.Select variant')</div>
                    <ul class="radio-check-list">
                        @foreach(\App\Models\ServiceVariant::where('service_id', 4)->get() as $variant)
                            <li>
                                <label class="radio-check">
                                    <input type="radio" wire:model="variant_id" name="variant_id" value="{{$variant->id}}">
                                    <span>{{$variant->t('name')}}/ {{$variant->price->price}} AZN</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="one-benefit-modal">
                    <div class="caption-m">@lang('app.Payment')</div>
                    <ul class="radio-check-list">
                        <li>
                            <label class="radio-check">
                                <input type="radio" wire:model="payment" name="payment" value="card">
                                <span>@lang('app.Card')</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        @if(Auth::guard('web')->check())
                            <li>
                                <label class="radio-check">
                                    <input type="radio" wire:model="payment" name="payment" value="balance">
                                    <span>@lang('app.From balance') ({{Auth::guard('web')->user()->fullBalance()}} AZN)</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-dark secondary mb-16 btnSend height-48 full-width" @if (is_null($payment) || is_null($variant_id)) disabled @endif>@lang('app.Pay')</button>
            @endif
        </form>
        <div class="close-modal-bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

ReturnAd.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Mail\Email;
use App\Models\Estate;
use App\Models\Payment;
use App\Models\PaymentHistory;
use App\Models\ServiceVariant;
use App\Models\ServiceVariantPrice;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\Models\TemplateNotification;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserLimit;
use App\Models\UserNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Livewire\Component;

class ReturnAd extends Component
{
    public $payment;
    public $variant_id;
    public $estate_id;
    public $template = 'full';
    public $estate = null;

    public function mount()
    {
        if ($this->estate_id) {
            $this->estate = Estate::find($this->estate_id);
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.return-ad');
    }

    public function pay()
    {
        
    }

    public function byLimit()
    {
        
    }

    public function moveToActive()
    {
       
    }

    public function updated($propertyName, $value): void
    {
        \Log::info("Властивість $propertyName була змінена на: $value");
    }
}

When I select the option and payment - the button does not become active. Nothing is written in the logs either. Why might the values ​​not update?
I tried to display payment and variant_id in the template - they do not change.
I use Laravel 10 and Livewire 3

Since Livewire 3, the attribute is not updated immediately. You need to change wire:model to wire:model.live.
<input type="radio" wire:model.live="payment" name="payment" value="balance">

You can read about that here: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#wiremodel

thanks, it really works. but now another problem. since it's a modal window, it closes when I select something

This depents on how you open that modal.

when clicking on the button. and is it possible to make it not close?
